# Solving Complex Valued Equalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking the following. Say I want to solve

$$
(i)^z=\sqrt 3 +2i.
$$

Usually, at least the way I have been taught, we write in polar form the other side of the inequality as
$$
(i)^z =e^{\pi/3+2\pi ik}
$$
and the left-hand side as
$$
(e^{\pi/2})^z =e^{\pi/3+2\pi ik}
$$
and then solve by expanding $z=x+iy$ in real and imaginary powers.

**My (quick ) question:** Don't we need to also consider $i$ as $i=e^{\pi/2+2\pi ni}$? When doing so I get more solutions.

**Remark**: I don't need someone to do the algebra for me, I just need someone to tell me what generality we need consider.

Comment: The re-write of $i^z$ should be $e^{\pi i/2 }z.$

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well start with $e^(i t)=\cos t + i \sin t$ where $i$ is the "imaginary unit" and satisfies $i^2=-1.$ In this put $t=\pi/2$ and use that $\cos \pi/2=0,\ \sin \pi/2=1.$ This gives $e^i (\pi/2)=0+i(1)=i.$ Note you only need the $+2 \pi n i$ on one side of your equation, since having it on both sides (with on one side the $n$ replaced by $m$) gives the same collection of solutions as from having it on only one side.

Comment: Repairing @coffeemath's typo: $i^z=e^{{\pi i \over 2}z}$... but/and, also, $i^z=e^{({\pi i\over 2}+2\pi i n)z}$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are calculating $~\displaystyle A = \left[re^{i\theta}\right]^{x + iy},$ you normally adopt some sort of constraint on $\theta$ confining it to a half-open interval of width $2\pi$.  This is because you want $A$ to evaluate **unambiguously**, for each value of $z = (x + iy)$.

I will adopt the arbitrary convention that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi.$

Then, $~\displaystyle i = [0] + i[1] = \cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2) = e^{i\pi/2}.$

The value $z_1 = \sqrt{3} + 2i$ may be expressed as

$\displaystyle \sqrt{7} \times \left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}} + i\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\right].$

Let $\alpha = \text{Arccos}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}}\right).$

Then, $z_1$ may be expressed as $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{7}e^{i(\alpha + 2k\pi)} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z}.$

---

**Edit**
Note that $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^2 = 1.$

---

This means that any value of $z = (x + iy)$ that results in

$$\left[e^{i(\pi/2)}\right]^{(x + iy)} = \sqrt{7}e^{i(\alpha + 2k\pi)} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z} \tag1 $$

must be construed to be a solution.

The constraint in (1) above may be equivalently expressed as

$$e^{-y\pi/2} \times e^{ix\pi/2} = e^{\log(\sqrt{7})} \times e^{i(\alpha + 2k\pi)} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z}. \tag2 $$

Therefore, the set of all satisfying values $(x + iy)$ is given by

- $\displaystyle -y\pi/2 = \log(\sqrt{7})$
- $\displaystyle x\pi/2 = \alpha + 2k\pi ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z}.$